# Check for vulnerabilities on website having an error with realpath PHP

Tags: php, url, path-injection

I found a website with a `download.php` file which can get different values in the `url` parameter (e.g. `www.example.com/download.php?url=value`). When I give `../../` as a value for the `url` it throws me the following error on the page:

```
Warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: open_basedir restriction in
effect. File(/srv) is not within the allowed path(s): 
(.:/srv/www/example.com/:/tmp/:/usr/local/php526/lib/php/) 
in /srv/www/example.com/download.php on line 5
```

I searched for the vulnerabilities of the PHP `realpath()` function in `PHP 5.26` or below and I found an [article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17407/how-can-i-use-this-path-bypass-exploit-local-file-inclusion) about PHP's file handling system and attacks using this method.

I would like to access the /etc/passwd/ directory as a file so I could get more information.
I have tried using a url which is longer than 4096 bytes but it does not seem to be truncated and happens nothing.

```
www.example.com/download.php?url=../../etc/passwd/././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././/./././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././././.....<...>.php
```

`curl --head website.com` returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 11:39:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.23 OpenSSL/0.9.8h
Content-Type: text/html
```

How could I exploit and bypass the website using LFI or Path Truncation? Or what is the best method to take advantage of this error?

Comment: Did you try to execute inside the local folder?

Comment: You mean `www.example.com/download.php?url=../../local/etc/passwd/././` ...

Comment: The truncation bug has to be correctly aligned, and you’re not traversing up enough directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear: File(/srv) **is not within the allowed path**.
So - no, you cannot access the /etc/passwd/ directory.

The answer you mentioned explicitly states

> No white/black lists, **open_base_dir** or any restrict access configuration

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is a Local File Include and not a path traversal or arbitrary file read vulnerability? LFI allows code execution which should let you run commands that are not bound by PHP’s path restrictions.

If it is an include call you may be able to execute an uploaded file from within /tmp since that path is allowed. Although you would need to fix your payload, you need to go up 3 directories, and you’re only going up 2. Otherwise using wrappers like php:// may be possible.

A simple check to see if it is LFI can usually be done by trying to read the download.php script itself. A script which includes itself should segfault or error out. If however you receive PHP source, then the file is read instead of executed and it not LFI, but traversal or arbitrary read. In this case you could leak all the application source code and look for other vulnerabilities.